# How to install support for WebLogic 9.2 in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, weblogic

The additional server adapters I installed only support WebLogic 10 and onward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/index.html). Under "[Features](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/weblogicservertools-161590.html)", it says:

> Full support for versions 9.2 through 10.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

At the time WebLogic was at version 9.2, the vendor was BEA, not yet Oracle. So, you should either look for BEA server adapters in your Eclipse installation or try to download additional BEA server adapters, in case you can't find the right one. I'm currently using Eclipse Indigo, and I have downloaded additional Oracle adapters (because I'm using WebLogic 10.3). However, when I try to add a new server and look into BEA adapters, WebLogic 9.2 is already there. I guess it already comes with Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of oracle weblogic server tools says it supports weblogic 9.2.  See [Cannot install Oracle Weblogic Server Tools in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508100/cannot-install-oracle-weblogic-server-tools-in-eclipse/70573485#70573485) for how to install it in a current version of eclipse.