# Cannot install Oracle Weblogic Server Tools in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, server, eclipse-plugin, weblogic

I came across this error when installing Oracle Weblogic Server Tools from eclipse:

> Software being installed: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 17.2.0.201806071916 (oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.feature.group 17.2.0.201806071916)Software currently installed: JustJ OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete 15.0.2.v20210201-0955 (org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.feature.group 15.0.2.v20210201-0955)Cannot satisfy dependency:Cannot satisfy dependency:Cannot satisfy dependency:Cannot satisfy dependency:Cannot satisfy dependency:Cannot satisfy dependency:

Please help. I searched for the solution for so long but nothing worked.

Comment: Is that really the full message? It looks like it is missing the actual dependencies.

Comment: I asked the nearly the same thing about nearly the same forum post, where I didn't get any kind of reply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recently installed oracle weblogic server tools in eclipse 2021-06.  The steps required in my environment were as follows:-

- In eclipse, go to `Help > Install New Software...`
- Click on `Manage...` to view the available software sites
- Make sure https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/photon/stable/updates/ is in the list of available software sites (click `Add...` to add it if required).
- Back in the Install dialog, enter the following site into the `Work with:` input field http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.10/photon/repository/
- When selecting which software to install, only select `Tools > Oracle Weblogic Server Tools`
- Click `Next` and complete the installation.

For me, the key was making sure https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/photon/stable/updates/ was an available software site so eclipse could download some other dependencies required by Oracle Weblogic Server Tools.  Also making sure nothing else except Oracle Weblogic Server Tools was selected helped reduce the dependencies that were required to be installed.

update 2022-07-25

I've successfully installed weblogic server tools in eclipse 2022-06.  I did have to configure  eclipse 2022-06 to run using java 11 instead of java 16 that it comes with to get this working.  I did this by creating a shortcut to eclipse and adding the -vm option to the command line when launching eclipse.

Comment: This workaround works with eclipse 2021-12 too.

Answer (score 0):

If https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/photon/stable/updates/ is already added press reload, it worked for me. 2021 -09

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is the additional insight this post is supposed to contribute on top of the existing other answer which seems to already include what you propose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70573485/7733418

Comment: I assume the addition is the bit about reloading if it's already added.  It's rather unclear, though.